# The following code fails the test for values such 1000 but for something like 4 it runs well

Tags: javascript

> Sum All Odd Fibonacci Numbers
> Given a positive integer num, return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to num.
>
> The first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are 0 and 1. Every additional number in the sequence is the sum of the two previous numbers. The first seven numbers of the Fibonacci sequence are 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 and 8.
>
> For example, `sumFibs(10)` should return 10 because all odd Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to 10 are 1, 1, 3, and 5.

I submitted the following code which did not pass all the tests:

```
function sumFibs(num){
  const fibonaciArr = [0,1];
  let add = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if(fibonaciArr[i+1]%2 !== 0) add+=fibonaciArr[i+1];
    fibonaciArr.push(fibonaciArr[i] + fibonaciArr[i + 1])
  
  }
  return add;
}
```

I used the fibonaciArr to come up with the sequence just to see whether the sequence is ok.

Comment: You're not checking that the Fibonacci number is less than `n`, you're creating `n` Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: You don't need an array, just two variables for the last two Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: It's a fast-growing number problem closer than the above ones.

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonacci numbers grow pretty fast. Using your code, `sumFibs(76)` is the last value that can be represented exactly in JavaScript or in any other language that uses the [double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) to represent the real numbers. This format can represent exactly the integer numbers in the interval -2<sup>53</sup> + 1 to 2<sup>53</sup> - 1. JavaScript provides the constants [`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER) and [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) for these values.

The values outside this interval are rounded to the nearest multiple of a power of 2. The values between 2<sup>53</sup> and 2<sup>54</sup> - 1 are rounded to the next multiple of 2, the values between 2<sup>54</sup> and 2<sup>55</sup> - 1 are rounded to the next multiple of 4 and so on.

This means that the 77<sup>th</sup> and the subsequent Fibonacci numbers cannot be computed. They are rounded to even numbers and your code ignores the even numbers.

You can solve this by using [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) numbers.

```js
function sumFibs(num){
  const fibonaciArr = [0n, 1n];
  let add = 0n;

  for (let i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
    if (fibonaciArr[i + 1] % 2n !== 0n) {
      add += fibonaciArr[i + 1];
    }
    fibonaciArr.push(fibonaciArr[i] + fibonaciArr[i + 1])
  }

  return add;
}

console.log(sumFibs(76));
console.log(sumFibs(77));
console.log(sumFibs(100));
console.log(sumFibs(1000));
```

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##fZC7jsIwEEX7fMWlQIqVBSVbQOFNsc3@BEoR8gCvkjHyYxvEt4eZSEggYBvbuufOsezf@q/2jTOnsCLbdtPUR2qCsQQfxx@z9ynFUZ0ToLHkA3qzt1Q35ts5lNjl9IGCKs186ALqtuU0J51w0FuHVFIjmebtCyyTQ5YpiBMwPdI7544ZigpLfBIWpbhuTcz2rMRzXc@Fy7ze0fUp@uOjveL@87xKZJoX14XoSC7SCQfyZDt068Ee0tt3bDdK6ddk@44Uef4PEjZNVw).

Read about how [JavaScript works with numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Answer (score 0):

Axiac's answer perfectly addressed the problem. I just add that you can easily solve this problem in JavaScript by using [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) numbers in place of plain numbers.

In order to do so, you have to place a `n` after every your number literal:

```
function sumFibs(num){
  const fibonaciArr = [0n, 1n];
  let add = 0n;
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if(fibonaciArr[i+1]%2n !== 0n) add+=fibonaciArr[i+1];
    fibonaciArr.push(fibonaciArr[i] + fibonaciArr[i + 1])
  
  }
  return add;
}
```

```js
function sumFibs(num){
  const fibonaciArr = [0,1];
  let add = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if(fibonaciArr[i+1]%2 !== 0) add+=fibonaciArr[i+1];
    fibonaciArr.push(fibonaciArr[i] + fibonaciArr[i + 1])
  
  }
  return add;
}

function sumFibsBigInt(num){
  const fibonaciArr = [0n,1n];
  let add = 0n;
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if(fibonaciArr[i+1]%2n !== 0n) add+=fibonaciArr[i+1];
    fibonaciArr.push(fibonaciArr[i] + fibonaciArr[i + 1])
  
  }
  return add;
}

console.log(`Fib(1000) with plain numbers: ${sumFibs(1000)}`);
console.log(`Fib(1000) with BigInt numbers: ${sumFibsBigInt(1000)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the Fibonacci sequence can get big pretty fast,.

But since we are dealing in integers, you can convert your code into using `BigInt`.

Below is an example.

```js
function sumFibs(num){
  const fibonaciArr = [0n,1n];
  let add = 0n; 
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if(fibonaciArr[i+1]%2n !== 0n) add+=fibonaciArr[i+1];
    fibonaciArr.push(fibonaciArr[i] + fibonaciArr[i + 1])
  }
  return add;
}

document.body.innerText = sumFibs(1000).toString();
```

```css
body {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong condition in your loop. You are checkig if index less than given number. Instead you need to check generated fibonaci number but not the index. Please try code below, should works fine (at least it works fine with 10). Have no idea what it should give for 100 but it gives 188, 1785 for 1000. Hope it is correct:

```
    function sumFibs(num){
      const fibonaciArr = [0,1];
      let add = 0;
      for(let i = 0; fibonaciArr[i+1] <= num; i++){
    console.log(i, fibonaciArr[i]);
        if(fibonaciArr[i+1]%2 !== 0) add+=fibonaciArr[i+1];
        fibonaciArr.push(fibonaciArr[i] + fibonaciArr[i + 1])
      
      }
    console.log (fibonaciArr);
      return add;
    }
```

EDIT: remove console.log-s to clean above code. However it is quite useful for debug and see what happens inside code.